# pointer to array in C : Address Arithmetic and Array Assignment

Tags: c, pointers

I have following pointer to array variable.

```
 int (*p)[3];
 int a[3]  = { 1,2,3 } ;  
 int b[3]  = { 11,22,33 } ;  
 int c[3]  = {111,222,333} ;
```

I want to store these 3 array into variable p.  How i have to allocate the memory for p
and How should i store these 3 array into p like  **array of pointer**. Whether is this possible ...? and How..?

Note:

> p = (int (*)[])malloc(3);
>  Now this p is capable of pointing three
>   integer array which size  3 . How i have to assign these a,b,c to this
>   p ?

.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understood the question. Could you precise the complete type ? Such as : an array of pointers to int, or an array of pointers to an array of int ?

Comment: The malloc in your code allocates 3 bytes, it's not capable of pointing three integer array as you expect, because the size of a pointer is at least 4 bytes on any modern computer.

Comment: Correction : you mean `p = (int (*)[])malloc(3*sizeof(int*));`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to allocate memory, it's allocated when you declare your array of pointers. Each pointer should point to the memory already allocated, but `a`, `b`, `c` are allocated automatically/statically, so you don't need to worry about that. Just assign them to the members of the array `p` and you're done.

If `p` is a pointer to array, then code should be:

```
int **p = malloc(sizeof(int*)*3);
...
p[0] = a; p[1] = b; p[2] = c;
...
free(p); /* when done*/
```

Declaring `int *p[3]` creates array of pointers, not pointer to array.

**edit**

If you want a pointer to an array then you can do this:

```
int a[3];
int *p = a;
```

And don't forget - you can use `a` on its own as a pointer to array it represents, where needed, you don't need a separate variable.

Comment: see there , i have created pointer to array ... not a array of pointer

Comment: ok, you confused me. pointer to what you created there? to `int[3]`? My answer still holds, it doesn't really matter to `malloc`, all the pointers are of the same size.

Comment: that's right. But I want to assign to pointer to array variable .  not a  array of pointer or pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int* p[3];
int a[3] = { 1,2,3 } ;
int b[3] = { 11,22,33 } ;
int c[3] = { 111,222,333} ;

p[0] = a;
p[1] = b;
p[2] = c;
```

That's it.

**Edit 1**

A pointer to array ?

```
int** p;
int a[3] = { 1,2,3 } ;
//...
p = &a;
```

**Edit 2**

And a array of pointers to array of int :

```
int** p[3];
int a[3] = { 1,2,3 } ;
//...
p[0] = &a;
//...
```

Comment: Is that what you asked for ? If not, could you precise or rephrase your question ? Please note that an array _is_ a pointer to the first value of the array, so it might be confusing you. If you describe what you want to do with it, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @littleadv: http://codepad.org/PqhfK8fq
I was talking about the code before the first edit.

Comment: @Aditaya I never put an `int (*p)[3];`, it always was a `int* p[3];` (if I'm not mistaking). The code you pasted was a mix of the question's code and mine. (thanks for the link to codepad by the way, never heard of it before)